# Slow transfer using NFS on one server (Proxmox reason ?)

Tags: nfs, proxmox, synology

It was hard to choose topic for my question so I describe my problem.

**I have two servers with Proxmox** (SERVER1 (proxmox version: 5.4-13) and SERVER2 (proxmox version: 5.2-12)) **and two NFS servers** (BACKUP and HOME).

HOME is a NAS Synology DS218 connect via LAN.

**My problem is totally different transfers between servers and NFS servers.**

I've tested using dd transfers. Here are results:

**SERVER1 -> HOME:**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 229.058 s, 2.9 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 132.96 s, 5.0 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 126.139 s, 5.3 MB/s
```

**SERVER1 -> BACKUP (transfers are ok):**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/KIMSUFI-BACKUPER/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k 
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 57.4353 s, 11.7 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/KIMSUFI-BACKUPER/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 57.3739 s, 11.7 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/KIMSUFI-BACKUPER/dwsrv bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 57.7291 s, 11.6 MB/s
```

**SERVER2 -> HOME:**

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/intel bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 35.8503 s, 18.7 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/intel bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 30.0541 s, 22.3 MB/s

dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/pve/DOM/intel bs=64k count=10k
671088640 bytes (671 MB, 640 MiB) copied, 44.8764 s, 15.0 MB/s
```

**Speedtest for SERVER1:**

```
Download: 794.86 Mbit/s
Upload: 243.54 Mbit/s
```

**Speedtest for SERVER2:**

```
Download: 827.50 Mbit/s
Upload: 245.85 Mbit/s
```

**Speedtest for HOME (I have 500DL/50UL MBit/s):**

```
Download: 209.42 Mbit/s
Upload: 55.07 Mbit/s
```

*Why I get approx 5 MB/s from SERVER1 to HOME when from SERVER2 to HOME I have approx 18 MB/s?*

*How can I check, why I get slow transfer from SERVER1 to HOME?*

Comment: for me it looks right as you only own 50mbit upload

Comment: From SERVER I have 250 MBit upload and HOME has 500 MBit download. So connection is ok.

Comment: hm, have you tried with a other protocol, not that your isp throttling nfs/samba

Comment: It's weird because from SERVER2 to HOME I have correct transfer. So my ISP doesn't block or cut transfer.

Comment: where are the server located?

Comment: So you Start - France. My NAS - Poland.